# Adding option to select dynamically with jquery is producing side effects

Tags: jquery, html

My jquery script:

```
var categorias = ["A","B","C"];

$(document).ready(function () 
  {
      $.each(categorias, function(index,item){
      $("#mycategoria").append(new Option(item))
  });

});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inserir obra</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="categorias.js"></script>
    <script src="instrumentos.js"></script>
    <script src="obra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Inserir obra</h3>

            <label for="mycategoria">Categoria: </label>
            <select id="mycategoria" name="categoria"/>

            <p>Isto é um teste</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**The problem:**

When I open the HTML page the `p` element is swallowed by select. Why?

Comment: a `select` element isn't self closing element, you need to use closing `</select>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close the select tag...

```
<label for="mycategoria">Categoria: </label>
            <select id="mycategoria" name="categoria">
            </select>

<p>Isto é um teste</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close `select` tag -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inserir obra</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="categorias.js"></script>
    <script src="instrumentos.js"></script>
    <script src="obra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Inserir obra</h3>

            <label for="mycategoria">Categoria: </label>
            <select id="mycategoria" name="categoria"></select> <!-- close it-->
            <p>Isto é um teste</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have still an extra `/` in select HTML markup :)